# OpenCV unable to create ffmpeg video writer

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I am working on an implementation OpenCV into a c++ project to create videos from image frames. This generally works when the video is fully uncompressed. To reduce the otherwise massive filesizes, I am trying to utilize ffmpeg, which is delivered alongside OpenCV.

```
cv::VideoWriter output_video = cv::VideoWriter(output_filename.c_str(), -1, 25, size);
```

In any case, the creation of an `ffmpegWriter` fails when creating the video writer object. While stepping through the OpenCV code, the `opencv_ffmpeg.dll` library is loaded and the various functions' addresses located successfully within the library. Finally, the following bit of code (`cap_ffmpeg.cpp`) is reached:

```
virtual bool open( const char* filename, int fourcc, double fps, CvSize frameSize, bool isColor )
{
    icvInitFFMPEG::Init();
    close();
    if( !icvCreateVideoWriter_FFMPEG_p )
        return false;
    ffmpegWriter = icvCreateVideoWriter_FFMPEG_p( filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize.width, frameSize.height, isColor );
    return ffmpegWriter != 0;
}
```

and `icvCreateVideoWriter_FFMPEG_p` always returns 0.

OpenCV does not supply a debug built of the `opencv_ffmpeg.dll` (and I found a post somewhere on their website that there is none available) so I have no possibility to check further what happens in the called function.

I tried this with OpenCV version 2.4.8, 2.4.13.4 and 3.3.1 with the same result in all cases. OpenCV is built from sources (with `HAVE_FFMPEG`), everything on a Windows 10 64bit machine in Visual Studio 2015.

Note: This is independet of the provided filename or fourcc code since OpenCV tries to find a working API for creating the video before anything else is evaluated. In my case the API is ffmpeg and creating the writer fails as described above.

The output of `cv::getBuildInformation()` is:

```
....
FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
  avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.89.100)
  avformat:                  YES (ver 57.71.100)
  avutil:                    YES (ver 55.58.100)
  swscale:                   YES (ver 4.6.100)
  avresample:                YES (ver 3.5.0)
....
```

Does someone has an idea what may be the cause for this issue or how I can further debug this?

Comment: Post the code where you create `videowriter`.

Comment: @zindarod I added the call but as stated in the note, it does not really matter since the opencv -> ffmpeg API call is done before any of the parameters are evaluated. I also tried thie earlier with many different parameters for the fourcc value without any difference

Comment: Call function `cv::getBuildInformation()`. In the output text find the string `FFMPEG`, post it's value.

Comment: @zindarod added

Comment: Coincidentally, I was just struggling with this exact issue.  In my case, I was trying to write an MPEG-4 file with `CV_FOURCC('D','X','5','0')` -- not sure what you're using.  

I found that the filename extension specified mattered.  `.mp4` and `.mpeg4` did not work, but `.avi` did.

Comment: @AndyDennie My current tests are all with `.avi` so that should not be the issue but thanks for the input